# Github trying to avoid being asked for credentials every time

Tags: git, github

I was working on our lab server and Github kept asking my username and password every time I tried to push or pull. After done some searching, I tried this command `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git` where `username` is replaced by my email address. Now I seemed now able to push to my repo. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), post the text itself instead.

Answer (score 2):

A URL like `git@github.com:username/repo.git` uses the SSH protocol for authentication. You need to create a SSH key and upload the public key to GitHub. [The GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) explain how to do this in detail.

Comment: Thank you. After adding a SSH key, I now get the error: ```yzr@umich.edu/repo is not a valid repository name```. Do you know how should I change the repo name on my server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTTP and don't mind your credentials being stored in plaintex you could use HTTP basic authentication:

```
https://username:password@git-repo/repo.git

#create a new remote with the authenticated url
git remote set-url authrepo https://username:password@git-repo.com/repo.git

#delete the old remote
git remote remove <your ocurrent remote>

#call the old remote the same as new remote
git remote rename authrepo <your current remote>
```